# Python 3 How to check if a value is already in a list in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists in my Python 3:

```
mylist = [[a,x,x][b,x,x][c,x,x]]
```

(x is just some data)

I have my code which does that:

```
for sublist in mylist:
    if sublist[0] == a:
        sublist[1] = sublist[1]+1
        break
```

now I want to add an entry, if there is any sublistentry ==a

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to test the sublists:

```
if any(a in subl for subl in mylist):
```

This tests each `subl` but exits the generator expression loop early if a match is found.

This does *not*, however, return the specific sublist that matched. You could use [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator expression to find the first match:

```
matched = next((subl for subl in mylist if a in subl), None)
if matched is not None:
    matched[1] += 1
```

where `None` is a default returned if the generator expression raises a `StopIteration` exception, or you can omit the default and use exception handling instead:

```
try:
    matched = next(subl for subl in mylist if a in subl)
    matched[1] += 1
except StopIteration:
    pass # no match found
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with list comprehensions (well, generator comprehensions here):

```
inList = any(a in sublist for sublist in mylist)
```